# FCK Editor Alternatives

Tags: wysiwyg, fckeditor

I've been using the FCK Editor for several of my client sites in the past.  Recently due to some new browser security updates(I'm assuming) some of the functionality is now breaking.

I was planning on updating those sites to the most recent version, but sometimes I think the FCK is overly complex and tends to confuse my clients more than it helps them out.

What other HTML WYSIWYG (if there is such a thing) are good out there.  A few of the items I really like about the FCK that I would want to keep:

- Drop Down Styles based on CSS
- Auto Inserted HTML templates
- Auto Inserted HTML snippets
- File uploader / browser

Thanks

Comment: If you are prepared to pay for it and can use it on your project, CuteEditor does everything FCK does and a bit more.

Answer (score 9):

Aloha Editor is a modern alternative to TinyMCE and CKEditor. It allows you to have common textbox style WYSIWYG Editor as replacement for textarea, but it also allows you to editing most of the DOM elements directly. This makes real WYSIWYG possible. It supports a lot a fancy new HTML5 and CSS3 functions.

Aloha Editor comes with a repository API, an autocomplete for file/images/other objects and a file/image/other object browser.

http://www.alohaeditor.org/

Comment: Holey Cow!! This is amazing, great job.

Comment: This really is good, it's worth nothing it doesn't support ie6 though

Comment: A big gotcha about aloha is their license. You can't use it in your commercial projects unless you buy a license.

Answer (score 7):

To get those features you're most likely going to end up with a solution that's just as bloated as FCKEditor. radEditor is the most bloated piece of crap I've ever been forced to work with. The latest version is not any better despite their claims of improvement. Cute is OK but costs money. YUI looks nice but I haven't played with it enough to know how extensible or fast it is.

The last versions of FCK (2.6+) have been much better. The dialogs are no longer popup windows so they work in more browsers. The plugin model is better than the others I have tried and it's easy to configure in one place (I may be wrong but I think TinyMCE requires the config embedded with every instance). They all generate less-than-ideal markup but FCK does the best job, especially in the latest versions. Customize the FCK toolbars down to just the essentials and I think your clients will like it a lot more. Mine do.

Comment: Thanks,  Most likely I'm going to stick with the FCK because I know the code base and it does the things I need.  I wish upgrading it was easier.  I have too many plugins added that are going to break a simple update.

Comment: Use WinMerge or another diff tool. Makes it wayyyy easier

Comment: Agree on diff tools. Beyond Compare made my latest transitions practically painless.

Answer (score 5):

[Yahoo Editor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/editor/) from Yahoo YUI

**UPDATE:**

Rolling up the other answers:

[TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/)

[CuteSoft](http://cutesoft.net/ASP.NET+WYSIWYG+Editor/default.aspx)

and, of course, [Markdown](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/reverse-engineering-the-wmd-editor/) which is the one you used to type the question in.

Answer (score 4):

[TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/) is my personal favorite.  You'd have to shoehorn the rest in, however.

Comment: I second that, TinyMCE is my editor of choice. It doesn't come with Image/Doc management solution for free though so you either have to implement yourself or buy one http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/plugins_imagemanager.php http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/plugins_filemanager.php

Answer (score 2):

The next generation FCKEditor is available now in the form of [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/). I recently converted an application to use that having previously used FCKEditor and found it fairly straight forward.

Comment: CKEditor "just works" now where FCKEditor doesn't (has issues with FF). In addition, if the CKEditor UI is too complicated, you can customize the interface and add/remove/arrange buttons as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

[CuteEditor](http://cutesoft.net/ASP.NET+WYSIWYG+Editor/default.aspx)  (commercial versions for ASP, ASP.NET & PHP)

Comment: Thanks, but I try to stick with open source when it comes to stuff like this.  That way I can come back and tweak the code as I need and when I need to push more sites with the same code (I have several that make user of the editor), I don't have to worry about licensing issues.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking controls that are free or paid? If paid, the only one I use is Telerik's radEditor. Ridiculously flexible and you can turn off basically anything and everything and make it look however you want (i.e. it's skinnable).

Comment: I prefer to use controls that are free obviously, but if there was a really good alternative out there that I felt was compelling enough I would pay for it.

Comment: OK, then I reiterate my suggestion of using Telerik's radEditor. I've been using it for years and it is very nice.

Answer (score 1):

If you're already using jquery, then you may consider using markItUp! which is implemented as a jquery plug-in. It could be lighter than other editors with similar feature set which doesn't make use of any framework.

It supports HTML, Textile, Wiki Syntax, Markdown, BBcode. You can also use your custom syntax.

[http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/)

Answer (score 0):

You might consider the Rich Text Editor in Flex. (Or Silverlight, for that matter.) It's a bit more of a controlled environment.

Answer (score 0):

[netEditr.com](http://neteditr.com) is based on TinyMCE as the default WYSIWYG XHTML designer. Go have a test run and see if it fits your needs.